# How can I access a scene from another scenes script

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a homework assigned and I need the make a sound and music volume thing and I want it to be used in other scripts too.
What I mean is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3oSN.png)

So when I drag the slider value to 0.2 for example I want the audio source on the other scene to have volume 0.2, but I have no idea how thats made.
Thanks.
(I only have a plan but no code)
Also does anyone know why does it take forever to load when you save a script and go to unity:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ofXO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great way to do this is to use `static` variables that are actually defined for the class And can hold variables between scenes.

```
public class AudioManager
{
    public static float MusicVolume = 1f;
    public static float SoundVolume = .5f;

    public void SetVolume(float value) => MusicVolume = value;
}
```

To call them, you just need to write the full name of the class before the variable name.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip AudioClip;
    public void Shot()
    {
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(AudioClip, transform.position, AudioManager.SoundVolume);
    }
}
```

Remember that these are class variables will set in all instances of the same class. Also if you want your variables to be loaded after re-running the game. I suggest using `PlayerPrefs` for saving them.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would write a singleton script **AudioManager** that is set to **DontDestroyOnLoad**

It's just a script holding your AudioSources and that doesn't get destroy when you switch scenes.

---

Something like this

```
public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static AudioManager instance;

    [Header("AudioSources")]
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource musicSource;
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource soundSource;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // If you have AudioManager in every scene, you want to only keep the main one (the first one)
        if (instance != null && instance != this) 
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else 
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this); // This line will tell Unity to keep this gameobject when switching scenes
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can alter your audio sources as you wish, they won't get destroy after switching scene.

Comment: Oh okay let me see

Comment: But if I add this script in my menu and I need sound from the actual game, How do I make that?

Comment: This is not a script that is part of your menu. This is a script placed on an empty GameObject with a children by audio source. Then in your menu, you call a method of that script to alter your source(s) :)

Comment: God Im stupid so If I put it in menu and the game and change stuff in menu it will change in the game?

Comment: Don't put it in your menu. Put it at the root of your hierarchy. Then use your menu to alter the audio source as you did before. But since the audio source is hold by the audiomanager, it will be shared across every scenes

Comment: How Am I going to alter from menu without script IN menu?

Comment: How do you alter your audio source atm ?

Comment: Uh what ATM I just use audio source :/